# Indexing for 3 dimensional Numpy Arrays (convolutional network)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to write a function that performs Convolution, and I'm getting a little challenged trying to create the output volume using numpy. Specifically, I have an input image that is represented as an array of dimensions (150,150,3). Now, I want to convolve over this image with a set of kernels num_kernels, which are arrays of dimension (4,4,3), and I want these kernels to move over the image with a stride of 2. My thought process has been:

(1) I'll create an output array which is comprised of taking (4,4,3) size chunks out of the input array and stretching these out into rows, and ultimately making a large matrix of these.

(2) Then, I'll create a parameter array composed of all of my (4,4,3) kernels stretched out into rows, which will also make a large matrix.

(3) Then I can dot product these matrices together and reshape the output matrix into the proper dimensions.

My rough psuedo-code start to number (1) is as follows.

```
def Convolution(input, filter_size, num_filters, stride):
    X = input 
    output_Volume = np.zeros(#dimensions)
    weights = np.zeros(#dimensions)
    #get weights from other function
    for width in range(0,150,2):
        for height in range(0,150,2):
            row = X(#indexes here to take out chunk).flatten
            output_Volume.append(row) #something of this sort
    return #dot product output volume and weights
```

If someone could provide a specific code example of how to implement this (most helpful would be answers to (1) and (2)) in Python (I'm using numpy), it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't a code providing service. However, we are welcome to help with specific issues you are facing and related questions. Please share any existing code and provide a **[mcve]**. This will help us provide better responses.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.